# Hibernate dont use dialect INNODB

Tags: spring, hibernate

Im using Spring and Hibernet to develop a Java webapp.

I want declare foreign keys, so I need use INNODB engine. I have declarated it at the datasource.XML, but the table are created automatically by Hibernate using MYSAM engine.

Here my Entity:

```
package com.atlantis.atecliente.model;

import java.util.List;
```

import javax.persistence.*;

```
@Entity
@Table(name="Expediente")
public class Expediente {
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private int codigo;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "tipoExpediente")
private TipoExpediente tipoExpediente;

@Column(length = 30)
private String estado;

public int getCodigo() {
    return codigo;
}

public void setCodigo(int codigo) {
    this.codigo = codigo;
}

public TipoExpediente getTipoExpediente() {
    return tipoExpediente;
}

public void setTipoExpediente(TipoExpediente tipoExpediente) {
    this.tipoExpediente = tipoExpediente;
}

public String getEstado() {
    return estado;
}

public void setEstado(String estado) {
    this.estado = estado;
}

}
```

And here the datasource.XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"     xmlns:jdbc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx 
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.1.xsd     http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc/spring-jdbc.xsd">

<!--    <jdbc:embedded-database id="dataSource" />-->

    <!-- data source for our database -->
<bean id="dataSource"
    class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName"
        value="com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.MysqlDataSource" />
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://SBPORTALPRE/atclientepre" />
    <property name="username" value="********" />
    <property name="password" value="********" />
</bean>

<bean id="sessionFactory"     class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
    <property name="packagesToScan">
        <list>
            <value>com.atlantis.atecliente.model</value>
        </list>
    </property>
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>

<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager"/>
<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory"/>
</bean>

</beans>
```

Some help please?

Comment: Make sure you don't have a hibernate.cfg.xml (or properties file) which overrides the properties. Your configuration is also of, the `DriverManagerDataSource` needs a jdbc driver class not another DataSource `implementation`.

Comment: I dont have a hibernate.cfg.xml. But when deploy de application, show some interesting informattion:      15:12:38,459 INFO  [Environment] HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found                    
15:12:38,464 INFO  [Environment] HHH000021: Bytecode provider name : javassist      
15:12:39,675 INFO  [Dialect] HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect

Comment: Your property name is wrong you have `dialect` where as it should be `hibernate.dialect`. Now it is using a default one based on detection of the driver.

Comment: Yes.... it was the problem.... Thanks!!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error was at

```
<prop key="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect</prop>
```

The correct line is:

```
<prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect</prop>
```

Thanks